# Django: Need help for my urls. Will show my Web when I hit 127.0.0.1/

Tags: python, django, pythonanywhere

How can I make my django app when run the server then when I put 127.0.0.1 un my url wil show my created site.. not **127.0.0.1/posts**
Here's my urls.py for my site.

**admin urls.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^posts/', include("posts.urls", namespace='posts')),
]
```

**my urls.py on myapp**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin

from .views import (
    post_list,
    post_create,
    post_detail,
    post_update,
    post_delete,
)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', post_list, name='list'),
    url(r'^create/$', post_create),
    url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/$', post_detail, name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/edit/$', post_update, name='update'),
    url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/delete/$', post_delete),
]
```

My current project is that when I access it it should be **127.0.0.1/posts/**
I want my **post_list** show when I hit **127.0.0.1/**

I want to deploy it on pythonanywhere...
Hope you guys will help me..Thanks!!

Comment: The simple answer is make a url pattern that matches the base url, although you may want to take a look at the documentation to understand how the patterns work.

Comment: kinda new, still confuse on how urls works.

Comment: You should look at the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/urls/v).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to change your admin `urls.py`

before:

```
url(r'^posts/', include("posts.urls", namespace='posts')),
```

after:

```
url(r'',include('posts.urls', namespace='post')),
```

Answer (score 0):

`url(r'', include('posts.urls'))`

you should use this in admin urls.py